# Java design class with same validation rules for different types of objects

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns

I'm trying to design a class with several simple validation rules. These rules can be applied to different Hibernate entities (or DTOs) and I'd like to unify this class without creating different implementations.

I try to do this by using generics, but the problem is although each type of the validated object has particular getter (getCatalog), I can't call it using generics without implementing a common interface or extending an abstract class. I think interface for entity/dto in such case is not a good choice.

Validator class

```
public class Validator<T> {

public boolean validate(List<T> objects, Function<T, Catalog> catalogGetter) {

    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(objects)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (differentCatalogsInLoadExist(objects, catalogGetter)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (catalogForObjectNotExists(objects, catalogGetter)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean differentCatalogsInLoadExist(List<T> objects, Function<T, Catalog> catalogGetter) {
    return objects.stream()
            .map(catalogGetter)
            .map(catalog -> catalog.getCatalogCode())
            .distinct()
            .count() > 1;
}

private boolean catalogForObjectNotExists(List<T> objects, Function<T, Catalog> catalogGetter) {
    return objects.stream()
            .map(catalogGetter)
            .findFirst()
            .isEmpty();
}
```

}

My main goal is to get rid of this `Function<T, Catalog> catalogGetter` because it looks not as good as it could be..

Comment: If every entity has a catalog, than an interface `HasCatalog` is perfectly fine. (In a similar case, it is often useful to have `HasEmail` for different kinds of entities that have e-mail addresses, so your mail routines can take anything that implements it.)

Comment: Essentially, this question asks: 'does Java support duck typing' - and the answer is: it does, well, [*kinda*](http://thinking-in-code.blogspot.com/2008/11/duck-typing-in-java-using-dynamic.html)

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I think I should agree with you, I haven't found a better solution for my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far, unfortunately, I only managed to do it with reflection, often through helpers such as apache PropertyUtils:

```
Catalog c=(Catalog)PropertyUtils.getProperty(myObj, "catalog");
// Where myObj is some object  that has "getCatalog()"
```

AFAIK it's a trade off: reflection is powerful but skips many compile-time checks, going against Java's original strongly-typed tradition; the alternatives you presented (interface or explicit referral to MyClass::getCatalog) are error-proof but verbose and also pose a problem in frameworks which might accept new unknown bean classes.

If there are any news up to java 14 I've been unable to find them. Would be glad to hear if anyone knows otherwise.

Comment: Agree with you, reflection is a trade off and using of interfaces looks better in this case, thanks!